# Unable to evaluate expression error while trying to display PDF using memorystream

Tags: c#, pdf, sharepoint, memorystream

I'm trying to generate PDF of my SharePoint page but keep getting an "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack." error. Am I going about doing this the correct way?

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                SPSite spBtnSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
                SPWeb btnSPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
                string doclibURL = string.Empty;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(ms))
                    {
                        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
                        pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);
                        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

                        //For setting the PAGE SIZE
                        pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4);
                        Document document1 = new Document(pdfDocument, pdfDocument.GetDefaultPageSize(), false);
                        using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(hidText.Text, pdfDocument, properties))
                        {

                        }
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        byte[] bytesInStream = ms.ToArray(); // simpler way of converting to array
                        ms.Close();

                        if (bytesInStream != null)
                        {
                            Page.Response.Clear();
                            Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
                            Page.Response.ClearContent();
                            Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                            Page.Response.AddHeader("content-length", bytesInStream.Length.ToString());
                            Page.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);
                            Page.Response.End();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex_btnSubmit_Click)
            {
                Exceptions.SaveException(UserID, ex_btnSubmit_Click.Message, ex_btnSubmit_Click.StackTrace, (ex_btnSubmit_Click.InnerException != null) ? ex_btnSubmit_Click.InnerException.Message : "");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `ThreadAbortException` on `Response.End()`. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/threadabortexception-occurs-you-use-response-end), you should use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` instead of `Response.End()`.

Comment: Thank you, however now im finding that nothings happening after that. The code completes but no PDF gets displayed.

Comment: Are you sure that bytesInStream is not null?